# Why can't I ssh to a newly terraformed EC2 instance created from gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, terraform

I have a strange problem, and I need some advice about where I should start looking to troubleshoot it, so I will leave out the details, which I think will just confuse the issue.

I have created a pipeline in gitlab; it runs terraform, which creates a VPC, EC2 instance and other stuff on AWS. The terraform part works fine from my Linux command line, and after it has finished, I can `ssh` to the newly created instance. However, when I run it from gitlab, I can't. It runs successfully and produces exactly the same output, but when I try to connect with `ssh` from my command line, it just times out, and I'm confused.

So, is this likely to be a problem in my gitlab configuration, or it is to do with AWS? I'm new to all the technologies here, so I'm struggling.

Comment: Can you add the TF and Gitlab codes for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's hard to help without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as I found out after a while, was that in `gitlab`, it is 'advisable' (ie. necassary, actually) to save the state and plan, since they may otherwise be lost from one stage to another in the pipeline:

```
plan:
  stage: build
  script:
    - terraform plan -state=$STATE -out=$PLAN
  artifacts:
    name: plan
    paths:
      - $PLAN
      - $STATE
```

And so on - this saves the plan and state in files; according to advice from others it would be better to save them in a remote repository, but this will do for now, when I am still testing.

Answer (score 0):

How do you Provision the SSH key? Without seeing any code, having different keys might be the root cause here as a first assumption